# what is the maximum number of rational points of a curve of genus 2 over the rationals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves, diophantine-equations, rational-points

Conjecturally, there exists an integer $n$ such that the  number of rational points of a genus $2$ curve over $\mathbf{Q}$ is at most $n$. (This follows from the Bombieri-Lang conjecture.)

We are very far from proving the existence of such an integer, let alone find an explicit value which works.

My question is:

What is the best known lower bound for $n$?

One way to obtain a lower bound $m$ for $n$ is to prove the existence of a curve of genus $2$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ with at least $m$ rational points.

Comment: I thought the Bombieri-Lang conjecture implied the statement that the number of rational points lying on a genus $2$ curves over $\bf Q$ is bounded by a number depending on the rank of the Mordell-Weil group of the jacobian of the curve (by the work of Caporaso-Harris-Mazur). How would you prove that there is an absolute constant ? Even the conjectural "effective Mordell" does not seem to imply that.

Comment: Theorem 1.1. in  "UNIFORMITY OF RATIONAL POINTS" by 
 CAPORASO HARRIS and MAZUR states that, assuming the weak Lang conjecture, there exists a real number $c(K,g)$ such that for all curves $X$ over $K$ of genus $g\geq 2$, the number of $K$-rational points of $X$ is bounded by $c(K,g)$. So conjecturally, there really is a uniform bound on the number of rational points.

Comment: @Harry. Thank you for the reference. I wasn't aware of that result.

Comment: "One way to obtain a lower bound m for n is to prove the existence of a curve of genus 2 over Q with at least m rational points."

Is there another way?

Comment: @DamianRössler You may be thinking of an earlier conjecture of Lang's, which says that the number of integer points on a minimal equation for an elliptic curve is bounded in terms of the rank. This was generalized to the statement you made, which is weaker than the C-H-M result (contingent on Bombieri-Lang). Marc Hindry and I proved an analogue of Lang's elliptic curve conjecture for characteristic 0 function fields.

Answer (score 16):

I believe it is 642. See http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/recordcurve.html

Comment: This is correct (for smooth projective curves).

Answer (score 14):

Here is some more information.

1. The curve that establishes the current record is obtained from a K3
   surface $S$ that was found by Noam Elkies. $S$ is a double cover of
   ${\mathbb P}^2$ ramified above a smooth sextic $B$ that has lots of
   tritangent lines and also higher degree curves meeting it with even
   intersection multiplicity in all points.
   Pulling back any rational line $L$ in ${\mathbb P}^2$ to $S$ that is not tangent to $B$ gives a genus 2 curve $C$ on which all the tritangents induce pairs of rational points, and the same is true for the higher degree
   curves when they intersect $L$ in rational points. Of course, there can be additional rational points on $C$ that do not arise in this way.
   I found the record curve by a systematic search through rational lines
   of relatively small height. The previous record was 588 points, due to
   Keller and Kulesz. Their curve is of a special form and has 12 automorphisms defined over $\mathbb Q$; the 588 points come in 49 orbits. By contrast, the new record curve has minimal automorphism group (only the hyperelliptic involution).
2. The result of Caporaso, Harris and Mazur needs the weak Lang conjecture for varieties of arbitrarily large dimension. (I have seen Bombieri protest against the name `Bombieri-Lang Conjecture,' saying that he only ever made the conjecture for surfaces.) We know essentially nothing in this direction beyond what is covered by Faltings' result on subvarieties of abelian varieties (or can be deduced from that).
3. What is perhaps more convincing is the conjecture that there should be a bound in terms of the genus $g$ and the rank $r$ for the number of (geometric) points on a genus $g$ curve $C$ mapping into a rank $r$ subgroup of its Jacobian (under some embedding given by a base-point on $C$). This follows from the Zilber-Pink conjecture for families of abelian varieties. This of course implies a bound for the number of rational points on a genus 2 curve in terms of the Mordell-Weil rank of its Jacobian. If these ranks are bounded, then one would expect a bound on the number of rational points.
   But this is another open question. Perhaps the data in
   [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.4165) might be interesting.

**EDIT:** This statement ("Uniform Mordell-Lang") has by now
been proved in [work of Lars Kühne](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.10272),
building on [work
of Dimitrov, Gao and Habegger](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.10276). Another proof was given
by [Xinyi Yuan](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.05625).

4. Such bounds do exist (and are even explicit) when the rank $r$ is sufficiently small compared to $g$; concretely for $r \le g-3$ (which
   unfortunately does not tell us anything about the case $g = 2$). See [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1773) and [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00694) paper. For hyperelliptic curves, the bound can be taken to be $33(g-1) + 8rg \pm 1$ ($+$ when $r = 0$, $-$ otherwise).

Comment: According to sagemath your projective curve with many points is not smooth. Is this bug in sage? It claims the curve is not smooth at $(0:1:0)$.

Comment: @joro The closure of the affine curve in the standard projective plane is not smooth, indeed. If you take the closure in the weighted projective plane with weights 1 for $x$, 3 for $y$ and 1 for the "new" variable, you obtain a smooth projective model of it. If the equation is $y^2 = f(x)$, then the other affine chart is given by $u^2 = v^6 f(1/v)$. You can find more about this in http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/teaching/ArithHypKurven-SS2014/Skript-ArithHypCurves-pub-screen.pdf (these are some lecture notes of mine).

Comment: Thank you. Can some CAS do the computations for me for similar curves?

Comment: @joro You can use my "ratpoints" (which is also available in SAGE and Magma) to find the rational points up to height (= maximum of absolute value of numerator and denominator of the $x$-coordinate) $10^5$ or perhaps $10^6$. To find the larger points on the record curve, I used a supplementary program that uses known points to try to find new ones.

Comment: I meant CAS to tell me if the weighted projective curve is smooth.

Comment: @joro You don't need to use a CAS for that. You can check by hand that the two affine patches that cover the curve in the weighted projective plane are both smooth (in fact, for the second patch, you only have to check the points with $v = 0$; they correspond to the points "at infinity" on the original patch).

Comment: Thanks. I am working with curves defined by several polynomials.

Answer (score -4):

The way the question is formulated, the answer is unbounded,
since rational singular points can be unbounded.

For natural $n$, define $j(n)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-i)$.

Consider the curve $C_n : j(n)^2(x^5+13)=y^2$.

It is birationally equivalent to $x'^5+13=y'^2$ which is genus $2$,
so $C_n$ is genus $2$.

$C_n$ has the rational (singular) points $(1,0),(2,0),\ldots(n,0)$
which are unbounded, since $n$ is unbounded.