# Curves of high genus with many rational points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

The seminal theorem of Faltings confirms Mordell's conjecture: that is, curves of genus at least 2 have at most finitely many rational points. The proof of Faltings' theorem is not effective, meaning there is no way to estimate the number of rational points on a given curve.

What is the conjectured truth for these curves? In some cases, a curve with a large genus actually have no non-trivial rational points (such as Fermat curves). Do there exist algebraic curves with genus at least 2 and arbitrarily many rational points?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103327/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-rational-points-of-a-curve-of-genus-2-over-the-rat?rq=1

Comment: Perhaps not exactly a duplicate: here the genus is not fixed, if I understand correctly (but my english is poor). However I am completely ignorant: what is the genus of $y^m=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)$ ?

Comment: Of course you need to fix the genus, for example taking $y^2=(x-1)(x-2)...(x-2g-2)$ you get a curve of genus $g$ with at least $2g+2$ rational points.

Comment: The number of rational points on a given curve can actually be estimated, similarly to the bounds for the number of solutions in Roth's theorem. Ineffectivity means that there is no current procedure of determining the *set* of rational points on a given curve (or the set of solutions in Roth's theorem). It is, however, known that an effective version of the ABC conjecture would supply such a procedure.

Comment: In http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/101/3/759.short Gael Remond gives an explicit upper bound on the set of rational points of a plane curve.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is the unique polynomial of degree $2g+2$ whose values on $x=1,\dots, 2g+3$ are your favorite sequence of perfect squares, then $y^2=f(x)$, if smooth, is a curve of genus $g$ with $4g+6$ rational points. For a generic sequence of perfect squares it is smooth. The equation for making $f(2g+4)$ a perfect square is a quadratic form, hence satisfies the Hasse principle, so showing it has solutions $p$-adically for all $p$ could give a $4g+8$ lower bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is a conjecture of Lang that there is a bound depending on the genus only. Check out [Lucia Caporaso's paper](http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/users/caporaso/CountingPoints.pdf) (I am sure there are more recent references).

Comment: To be really precise: it is a "non-trivial" consequence of a conjecture of Lang that, for all integers $d$ and $g$, there exists a real number $c(d,g)$ depending only on $d$ and $g$, such that if $X$ is a curve of genus $g$ over a number field $K$ of degree $d$ (over $\mathbf Q$), then $\# X(K) \leq c(d,g)$. This is proven by Caporaso, Harris and Mazur using the "correlation theorem" for $d=1$, and by others (Pacelli and Abramovich?) for $d>1$.