# Uniform Faltings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Suppose I give you positive integers $g\geq 2$ and $N.$ Is it always possible to find an absolutely irreducible curve of genus $g$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which has at least $N$ rational points? For that matter, what if $g=2?$ I assume that the answer is **YES**, but what do I know?

Answer (score 17):

On the contrary, some conjectures suggest that the answer is *NO*! It follows from the Bombieri-Lang conjecture (sometimes known as Lang's conjectures) that a uniform bound should exist.

More precisely, given a number field $F$ and a genus $g\geq2$ BL implies that there's some bound $N(F,g)$ such that every smooth projective genus $g$ curve over $F$ has at most $N(F,g)$ points. Even better -- the bound depends only on the degree of $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, not $F$ itself.

The fact that Bombieri-Lang implies this was proved by Caporaso, (Joe) Harris and Mazur in 1997 and my recollection at the time was that some people regarded this as evidence against Bombieri-Lang rather than for the uniform bound. However, at this stage, the question is open, even for curves of genus 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I once saw a talk of Elkies where he exhibited a curve of genus 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$ with something like 588 rational points, but this may not be the record any longer.

Comment: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/many_pts.pdf is what looks like a write-up of what Elkies knew a while back. It will contain all the references you need. I quite agree that it's an extraordinary situation!

Comment: Wow, who would have thunk it!

Comment: Armed with your words of wisdom, I found this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103327/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-rational-points-of-a-curve-of-genus-2-over-the-rat